# convert independent intercept/slope mixed model formula into a math formula

Tags: r, mixed-models, multilevel-analysis

Within an R session I would have the following formula:

```
members ~ face + class + gender + number + (day || country)
```

How would I write this in a math formula? By the way, is it a random slope random intercept model?

Comment: Check out the equatiomatic package and see if that helps: https://datalorax.github.io/equatiomatic/

Comment: It would typically be called a "random slopes model with uncorrelated slopes and intercepts"

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr

[image: equation formula]

This is just the "hard part"; your covariates that aren't involved in the random-effects part of the model would get added as part of the first equation (`beta_2*face + beta_3*class + ...`).  (By the way, it's unusual [i.e. probably wrong unless you have some specific reason for doing it this way], if `days` is a continuous variable, to have it in the random-effects model and not in the fixed-effects model ...)

Using the development version of `equatiomatic` (note that most of the complexity here is for turning the results of `extract_eq()` into a PDF, then a PNG for posting here - requires some command-line tools (LaTeX, pdfcrop, ImageMagick).  There may be a way to do this in a more self-contained way with the `tinytex` package:

```
while (!require("equatiomatic")) {
    remotes::install_github("datalorax/equatiomatic")
}
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days||Subject), sleepstudy)
unlink("tmp.tex")

writeLines(c("\\documentclass{article}",
             "\\usepackage{amsmath}",
             "\\begin{document}",
             "\\thispagestyle{empty}",
             format(extract_eq(m1)),
             "\\end{document}"),
           con="tmp.tex")

system("pdflatex tmp.tex")
system("pdfcrop tmp.pdf")
system("convert tmp-crop.pdf tmp.png")
```

Comment: quick question why the alpha has those 2 indexes j adn i ? in your answer subjects should be the I index right ? also why then that alpha follows that normal distribution with the ~ in the equation? @Ben Bolker

Comment: `j` is the group (Subject) index, `i` is the observation index, `j[i]` means "the `j` corresponding to observation `i`".  Don't understand the second question.